# Kohana 3: Cookie::$domain cannot log in

Tags: php, session, cookies, kohana, kohana-3

I'm trying to make Cookie domain work in Kohana 3.1. it should be as simple as:

```
Cookie::$domain = '.mydomain.com';
```

But now i cannot login which was working before inserting the code. FYI: my domain name is beta.mydomain.com and trying to make the sessions accessible to beta.sub.mydomain.com etc..

Comment: `beta.sub.mydomain.com` is not a subdomain of `beta.mydomain.com`

Comment: explanation: apparently subdomain's cookies don't completely die in kohana even if you log out. these cookies are then prioritized when reading and not the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it. clear cookies

explanation: apparently subdomain's cookies don't completely die in kohana even if you log out. these cookies are then prioritized when reading and not the domain.